# How to send a cookie under a specific 3rd-party domain via curl in console

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cookies

```
curl -v --cookie "user_db=Tony" http://hostname/
```

The above command send a cookie **user_db** under domain **hostname**.
How to send a cookie under a specific 3rd-party domain such like hostname2?

Answer (score 0):

The given command sends the cookie named 'user_db' with contents 'Tony' in the HTTP request to 'hostname'.

If you'd change hostname to hostname2 instead, the cookie would be sent to that server instead.

For a client like this that sends a single HTTP request to a specific server, there is no 3rd party involved. You either send a cookie or you don't.